# Add Edit Text in toolbar on menu item's click

Tags: android

I have a search icon in the toolbar. What I want to do is to show the edit text field only when the user clicks on the search icon.

I've searched on the Internet but I couldn't find an answer. I set the visibility false of edit from the properties menu, and when the user clicks the search icon I try to set the visibility true, but it didn't work.

P.S I set the visibility true by:
    editText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: can you show the xml and code of searchview with your current implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `edittext` inside `RelativeLayout` with `layout_gravity` : top.
Then this `RelativeLayout` will be closing the toolbar.

So this is next you **must** do :

1. Icon search on the toolbar if clicked, give `RelativeLayout` Visibility= `visible`, and for toolbar Visibility : `invisible`
2. And give button close to the `RelativeLayout`, when that button is clicked, give the toolbar Visibility = `visible` and for `RelativeLayout` Visibility = `invisible`

There is way that i can see from whats up application.
You can use Visibility = `View.GONE`

This maybe can help you

Answer (score 1):

Try using following method:

inside Menu.xml file:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/search_view"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"/>
```

**search_view.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/searchIconImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_action_search"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchEditText"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white">

        <requestFocus/>
    </EditText>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/closeImageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_navigation_close"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Inside Java file, inside `onCreateOptionsMenu` method

```
searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
View view = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchMenuItem);
        closeSearchViewImageButton = (ImageButton) view
                .findViewById(R.id.closeImageButton);
        closeSearchViewImageButton
                .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(searchMenuItem);
                    }
                });

        searchEditText = (EditText) view
                .findViewById(R.id.searchEditText);
        searchEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {

            @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {
            }

            @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int
                                                                                          after)
            {
            }

            @Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {
            }

        });

        MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchMenuItem,
                                                 new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener()
                                                 {
                                                     @Override
                                                     public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(
                                                                                          MenuItem
                                                                                          item)
                                                     {
                                                         showKeyboard();
                                                         return true;
                                                     }

                                                     @Override
                                                     public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(
                                                                                            MenuItem item)
                                                     {
                                                         hideKeyboard();
                                                         return true;
                                                     }
                                                 });
```

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try Following solution:

Menu File:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/search_action"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:title="Search"/>
```

Inside Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu( Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    MenuItem actionSearch= menu.findItem( R.id.search_action);
    final SearchView searchViewEditText = (SearchView) actionSearch.getActionView();
    searchViewEditText .setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            return false;
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```